# Stuck adding formula to dynamically added columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a query that returns a dynamic number of columns. I need to dynamically add the same amount of custom columns. I have successfully gotten this far. I'm stuck creating the formulas for the custom columns. This is what I have so far. (This is not the actual query, this is simplified)

[image: What sample query looks like]

Here is the Code:

```
Test = List.Accumulate(MyList, Source, 
       (state, current) => Table.AddColumn(
           state, "A Temp" & Number.ToText(current), each [A1])
       )
```

For now, I just added [A1] as a place holder for the formula. I need the formula to accumulate as follows:

```
A Temp1 = [A1] / [TOTAL]
A Temp2 = [A2] / [TOTAL]
A Temp3 = [A3] / [TOTAL]
```

Above is not actual code. Just what I need the formulas to do for each custom column.

Is this possible? I have tried everything I could think of. I'm using power query in excel BTW.

Comment: How is `MyList` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but I think it will help.

```
Test = List.Accumulate(
           List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each _ <> "TOTAL"),
           Source,
           (state, current) => Table.AddColumn(state,
                                   "Temp " & current,
                                   each Record.Field(_, current) / [TOTAL]))
```

It's not exactly what you asked for as it gives column names like `Temp A1` instead of `A Temp1`.

Comment: That was exactly the rabbit hole I wanted to go down. I created a blank query that mimics all the steps I'm going to need to add to my project. Your solution worked perfectly. Working with dynamic data is a pain. You helped me solve for dynamic column names and dynamic quantity.